# Keep Authentication between different calls to java.net.URL

Tags: java, url, jenkins, hudson

I have a remote server that use basic authentication (HTTP) and i need several calls to different URLs. A example of calling:

```
URL address = new URL ("hhtp://localhost:8080");
HttpURLConnection connection;
// open connection
connection = (HttpURLConnection) address.openConnection();
String encoding = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary((username + ":" + password).getBytes());
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
// transform result code into an exception
int code = connection.getResponseCode();
if ((code < 200) || (code >= 300))
{
       throw new HttpRetryException(connection.getResponseMessage(), code, address.toString());
}
 return connection;
```

The problem appear that the server take a lot of time authenticating the user. After this first call, we need another page (a different URL) to the same server. How I can keep the session between different calls?

Edit:

A clarification, I'm trying to connect to a Jenkins server.

Comment: Does the server support sessions? How does it determine that a second request belongs to the same session?

Comment: Basic authentication doesn't (necessarily) involve sessions, you have to send the same Authorization header with every request.

Comment: Yes, it's support sessions. Using a web browser you only need authenticate once.

Comment: How can I get this Authorization header?

Comment: Not related to the question, but I'd go with [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/index.html) to solve this king of issue.

Comment: @FernandoRosado The web browser automatically resends the authentication info with each request, this is no proof that the server supports sessions.

Comment: But how can i obtain this information for resent it? I can not found it on header properties.

Comment: Thanks @GilbertoTorrezan, but I prefer don't use 3PP for a simple query. I will review the solution that Apache have used.